# proposal to re-open a question; also some other comments on it

Tags: discussion, re-open

I've voted to re-open [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184003/how-do-we-prove-that-a2b2-c2-for-a-right-angled-triangle).

I wouldn't be surprised if it should be closed as a duplicate, but closing it as "not a real question" was probably just people throwing tantrums.  At least ten people down-voted it.  I've up-voted it.

I get an impression from another thread on meta that some people think that any question that should be closed should also be down-voted.  I've actually up-voted some questions I thought should be closed as duplicates, and I'll probably do so on future occasions.

I find an admission in the last thread I started that some people here down-vote questions because they bear grudges based on the poster's earlier questions.  If some people are doing that, then the rest of us should explain to them that that's wrong.

Comment: What other "thread on meta that some people think that any question that should be closed should also be down-voted"?

Comment: @BillDubuque : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/downvoting-because-of-duplication  Carl Mummert is very confused.  I questioned whether one should down-vote a question merely because it's a duplicate.  Carl Mummert seemed to think I was questioning whether something should be _closed_ because it's a duplicate.

Comment: Carl's answer says nothing about *downvoting* duplicate questions; rather it addresses only the matter of *closing* them. While it appears the he may have misread your question, it also appears that you may have misread his answer.

Comment: I correctly read his answer as being about closing questions.  But it was phrased in a way that made it appear that he thought that's what my posted question was about.

Comment: But it does not, as you claim, state that "any question that should be closed should also be down-voted". Is that a strawman, or did someone really state that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I did not find the admission you mention. Where can I find it?

Comment: -1, due to the "admission" sentence.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general issue, I think, with the limited number of options given when someone votes to close a question. The "official" reason shown for a closed question has to be taken with a grain of salt for this reason. Moreover, only one reason for closing is given, even if some votes were for other reasons. So some voters might have actually chosen "duplicate" as their reason; the appearance of a name of a voter in the list of voters cannot be taken to mean that the voter chose the reason shown.

Comments are the only way for voters to actually express their reasoning for closing, and when none of the "official" reasons is accurate I always leave a comment with my full reasoning (I didn't vote on this question in any way).

Comment: I wonder whether it wouldn't be better to just not show the reason for closing (only the names), and expect a comment to be left explaining the rationale for voting to close.